# About Rigid monoidal subcategory

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoidal-categories

I have just sturted to study about monoidal categories and I am trying to solve this question...

Suppose $A=\mathbb{C}/(x^3)$ and $A_c$ be additive closure of $A$ and $A\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}A$ in $A-mod-A$. I need to show that $A_c$ is a rigid monoidal subcategory of $A-mod-A$.

I need to show each object in $A_c$ has both left and right adjoints... but I have no idea how...

Comment: What is $D-\text{mod}-D$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Maybe $D$ means $A$ and $D-mod-D$ is the category of $A$-$A$-bimodules ???

Comment: @QiaochuYuan sorry, I corrected it...

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, thank you, I messed up with notations so sorry

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez yes, direct sums and sumands